# How do i use chartjs in react project properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

Im trying to use chartjs in my react project but it doesnt work. What am i doing wrong?

You can see console logs here:

[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtSRL.png)

```js
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2";

const WeatherChart = () => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Bar
        data={{ labels: ["Red", "Blue"] }}
        width={100}
        height={50}
        options={{ maintainAspectRatio: false }}
      />
    </Container>
  );
};

const Container = styled.section`
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
`;

export default WeatherChart;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attributes you're passing to `Bar` are incorrect. Specifically, your `data` attribute is missing its own `datasets` attribute, as can be seen in the error log when `Chart.js` is attempting to call `setDatasets`.

Suppose you're charting the temperature for each day of the past week:

Your `labels` attribute:

```
const labels = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
```

Your `data` attribute:

```
const data = {
  labels,
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Temperatures',
      data: labels.map(() => Math.random() * 100),
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
    },
  ],
}
```

Your `options` attribute:

```
const options = {
  responsive: true,
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      position: 'top',
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Chart.js Bar Chart',
    },
  },
}
```

Pass them to the `Bar`:

```
return <Bar options = {options} data = {data} />
```

Your chart:

[image]

Learn more and see more examples in the [docs](https://react-chartjs-2.js.org/components).